# Show that $f(z)= \frac{-1}{z}$ maps each circle of the form $|z+ti| = (t^2-1)^{1/2}$ onto itself.

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Show that $f(z)= \frac{-1}{z}$ maps each circle of the form $|z+ti| = (t^2-1)^{1/2}$ onto itself

Comment: sorry about that,

Comment: Something is wrong. What happens when $|t|<1$?

Comment: This looks odd, @maria: should it be, perhaps, $\,|z|=1\,$ ? Otherwise I can't get the wanted equality, though perhaps I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C(0,-t)$ be the center of a circle in question, and let $T$ be either point of intersection of the variable circle and the Unit Circle; then,

$$|OC|^2 = t^2 = \left(t^2-1\right) + 1 = |CT|^2 + |OT|^2$$

so that $\triangle OTC$ is a right triangle with right angle at $T$: radius $OT$ is tangent to the variable circle. (Since radius $CT$ of the variable circle is likewise tangent to the Unit Circle, the circles are *orthogonal*. Depending on what you know about Möbius transformations, this (along with an observation about the location of $f(T)$) more-or-less ends the proof. However, I'll continue with an elementary geometric argument.)

Let $P := p \; \exp(i\theta)$ and $Q := q\; \exp(i\theta)$ be the two (possibly-coincident) points with argument $\theta$ that lie on the variable circle. By the [Power of a Point Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point), because $OT$ is tangent to the variable circle,
$$p q = |OP|\cdot|OQ| = |OT|^2 = 1$$

Now, note that 
$$f(P) = -\frac{1}{p\exp(i\theta)} = -\frac{1}{p}\exp(-i\theta) = q\;\exp(i\pi-i\theta) = q\;\exp\left(i(\pi-\theta)\right)$$
This says that $f(P)$ is the reflection of $Q$ across the $y$-axis. As the $y$-axis runs through the center of the variable circle, and $Q$ lies on that circle, this reflected point must lie on that circle, as well. **QED**